# how to retrieve name of image displayed by ImageView?

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

I have an android.widget.ImageView in an Android application. How can I get the name of the image it is displaying?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using from resource then you can get using [getResourceName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceName%28int%29)

```
String imageName = getResources().getResourceName(R.id.img);
```

Or You can get & set the image tag and use it.

```
imageView.setTag("android.png"); // using java 
android:tag="android.png" // using xml
imageView.getTag();
```

BUt if you are download from server or using for extranl path at that time you have to split your image path like

```
//Your last index value is your image name
String image_path = "this/is/chintan/khetiya/android.png";
String[] result = image_path.split("/");
for (int x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
    System.out.println(result[x]);
    Log.i("value", "" + result[x]);
}
```

**Result: android.png**

and last [Change your image name](http://getablogger.blogspot.in/2008/01/android-download-image-from-server-and.html) while you are downloading from server.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible out of the box. You'll have to save the image name when you set it, either in a custom `ImageView` subclass or in your `Activity`.

Comment: @chintankhetiya actually, your solution is just another workaround as the two possibilities I mention. What I mean is: There is no such method as `getDrawableName()` or `getImageName()`.

Comment: check my answer , yeah that is possible that if  encode url doesn't have specific image name at that time we have to save with specific name that i have mention in my answer. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @chintankhetiya the OP does not mention where the image comes from, whether it is a resource drawable or a file from the Internet, so I tried to keep my answer as general as possible.

Comment: FD_ that is good , and i have keep my answer with some alternative. thanks :)